# application/pdf タイプのレスポンスをNuxtプロジェクト上に表示したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nuxt.js, axios

NuxtとRailsを利用してpdfを生成しています。

生成gemとしてprawnを採用しており、適切なparamsをapiに送信した場合にpdfが作成されることを確認できています。

axios経由でこのAPIを叩いたとき、application/pdf型
のレスポンスを、Nuxtプロジェクト上でPDFとして表示したいです。

知見ある方いらっしゃればご教授願いたいです。
params

```
{
 name: "myName",
 address1: "Tokyo",
 address2: "Minato-ku"
}
```

request

```
const config = {
      responseType: 'blob',
}
const res = await this.$axios.post('/v1/orders', params, config)
=> res.data is like "Blob{size: 12345, type:"application/pdf"}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

受け取ったblobデータを `URL.createObjectURL` を使用して参照用のURLを生成できます

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

その後URLをpdf.jsを利用して表示すると良さそうです

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/